# Get Brightcove Video player name

Tags: brightcove

Anyone know a way to obtain the currently active Brightcove video player by name (as per video cloud account) via the Brightcove API ? Maybe I'm missing something simple, but I cant find it in any of the documentation

Cheers
J

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to get player info from the API

Answer (score 0):

According to the Brightcove support site:

> When you use a read method in the Media API to get a video, you specify which properties of the video you want to be returned with the video_fields parameter in the method call. For example, to get a video's name and duration, you might use a find_video_by_id call, as follows:
>
> http://api.brightcove.com/services/library?command=find_video_by_id&video_id=1520880903001&video_fields=name,length&token=jskS1rEtQHy9exQKoc14IcMq8v5x2gCP6yaB7d0hraRtO__6HUuxMg..

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but it might be a good place to start.

Comment: the media API provides information about the videos, not about account players.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the playerID

```
_videoPlayer = player.getModule(APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER) as VideoPlayerModule;
_videoPlayer.getID()
```

You can retrive aditional parameters from player configuration parameters:
http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/player-configuration-parameters

```
var playerOptions:Object = _experienceModule.getConfiguredPropertiesForID("videoPlayer");
var isAutostars:Boolean = (playerOptions["autoStart"]);
```